# Zlib deflate file when added as attachment in email could not open

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mime-types, zlib, email-attachments

I m using Zlib to compress a text file by using NSData category as discussed in http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory .

After compressing I m attaching the file to an email. When I open the email and download the compressed file I am not able to unzip the file. I m getting an error that the file is corrupted.

I am using @"application/x-deflate" as attachment mime type. And I m giving FileName.zip as file name of attachment when I m adding attachment to MFMailComposeViewController for emailing.

Am I right in giving the attachment type as @"application/x-deflate"? What to do in order to be able to unzip the file after downloading from email?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'application/zip' as the MIME type.

Comment: Does 'application/octet-stream' work? If not I'd suggest the problem is not with the MIME type you're specifying but maybe with the code you're using to create the zip file.

Comment: 'application/octet-stream' also did not work. To cross check the compressing code I have deflated and then inflated and send the file as its original mime type(which is text/plain in  my case) and it worked fine.